# Write text on the icon in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

[image]

And I am Using this code: how to set this kind of layout in flutter

```
Container(
      height: 200.0,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: Colors.blue, size: 200.0,)
          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try this, you have to just make `Stack` alignment to center and add a `Text` in `Stack` array.

```
Container(
      height: 200.0,
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.play_arrow,
              color: Colors.blue,
              size: 200.0,
            ),
            Text(
              "Play",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18,color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: That is Great and very simple !